# PowerBI number of days since view

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, measure

New to powerbi. How do I create a table visual that will give me those who have not logged in the past 30 days?

My output should show only Ben since he hasn't logged into either dashboards in the past 30 days.

```
Dashboard        User          Days since log in
Dasher 1         Ashley        30 
Dasher 2         Ashley        15
Dasher 3         Ashley        3
Dasher 1         Ben           30
Dasher 3         Ben           31
Dasher 1         Charlie Bob   2
Dasher 3         Charlie Bob   23 
Dasher 3         Charlie Bob   30
```

Comment: 30 day considering Today()? or selected date in slicer? Where is last login date column?

Comment: 30 days from Today(). There's a date column, i didn't add it in the example.

Comment: Add that date column for better understanding.